# Magento Search Grid PHTML file location

Tags: php, html, magento

Hello I am trying to fix an issue where our add to cart button does not work but only on our search results page so i'm asking if anyone knows where this file is located. My problem is that each product listing in category and search results page has a quick add to cart button which allows the user to add to cart without navigating to the product page.

This button works on the category pages fine however it does not work on the search results page and so I would like to take a look at the phtml file that is being used to generate the product listings in the search results. Template path hints does not work on my magento so I cannot turn this on to find the location of files unfortunately.

I think Ihave found the code for the category grid pages to be here app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/template/catalog/product/list.phtml 
and would like to know where the search page phtml file that is used for the product listings on a search result page.

Thanks Harri

Answer (score 2):

This is the path to the search page template.

```
app > design > frontend > [package] > [theme] > template > catalogsearch > result.phtml
```

It then calls in the same product list.phtml that your product page uses within it. You'll need to change the package and theme to whatever you're using.

I've just tested this button and it seems to work for me on the search page

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()):?>
    <button class="form-button" onclick="setLocation('<?=$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)?>')">Add to Cart</button>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: So its still using the same list.phtml file for each grid? As the code in the list.phtml must be working in the catagory page instance but not the search result instance.

Comment: Yeah it uses the same file. Have you created the add to cart button yourself? I'll post in the answer a snippet that works for me on search pages

Comment: Thanks but i am trying to also have a quantity field also , it seems to be something wrong with my <?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?> on search page i think. When I paste the url from a catalog grid into firebug on the search grid, clicking add to cart then will add the product which url i copied, into firebug into the basket but i don't know why the url is broken it still generated like so checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5idXp6Y2F0ZXJpbmdzdXBwbGllcy5jb20vY2F0YWxvZ3NlYXJjaC9yZXN1bHQvP29yZGVyPXJlbGV2YW5jZSZkaXI9ZGVzYyZxPWtuaWZl/product/96/

Comment: Try the solution in this answer to get a quantity box on it http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19365/how-to-add-quantity-option-to-each-product-item-in-the-category-list-page

Comment: I have tried a few different bits of code but am running into the same issue. When i press add to cart on the search page it basically runs a search query instead?